# sqlite3 library size on Android NDK is very large

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

I compiled the sqlite3 amalgamation into Android NDK, and I'm able to use it from my C++ code.  However, libsqlite3.a is 2.6MB.  This [link](http://www.sqlite.org/footprint.html) says the library size should be around 500KB for typical Linux/GCC systems with -O2.  I'm using NDK r6b to build, and didn't set an optimization level for the compiler, but the default is -O2.  Any idea why my library is so large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't measure library size from .a file. Measure linked size (from .so file).

Try stripping the .a library file, maybe it includes debugging symbols.

Comment: Also, I'm using "release" mode in Application.mk, which is supposed to generate "highly optimized binaries" according to the NDK documentation.

Comment: Release mode doesn't mean that it won't include debugging symbols. You can compile source code WITH optimizations and WITH debugging symbols. Try adding switch "--strip-debug" to strip command.